# How add dynamically Vue components with a parent Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to create dynamic Vue component with a parent Vue component,
but the dynamic component is not created,

I tried to add dynamic component to HTML by add new Child but is not working,,

```
<template>
  <div class="app-body row">
    <div class="widgets">
      <h1>new ems</h1>

      <div id="Device"><p>ems</p></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

export default {

created() {
    console.log('created');
this.displayWidget('Device');
},
methods:{
displayWidget(which) {
    let Child = Vue.extend({
        name: which,
        parent: this,

    });
    new Child({
        el: $(this.$el).find('.widgets')[0],
        template: '<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; color: yellow">Hello</div>', // tried just standard template stuff here
        render: h => h('div')
    }).$mount();
    }
    }
    }

   </script>
```

I get error: 
[Vue warn]:Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: $ is jquery : it's seems jquery is not imported or referenced...

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the element an id like `id="widgets"` and use `el: '#widgets'` - seems to work in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/flaviocopes/pen/YLoLOp)

You could also add a `ref` to the element like this

```
<div ref="widgets">
```

and then

```
el: this.$refs.widgets,
```

The reason you're getting the `ReferenceError` is probably because you haven't imported JQuery

Comment: now I get another error:  Cannot find element: #widgets, also I try your  example exactly